# Custom WebControl is listed in an UpdatePanel's list of asyncpostback triggers, but still causes a full, synchronous page refresh when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, triggers, updatepanel

I'm trying to build a UserControl; a visually customizable LinkButton. All was well until UpdatePanels came into the mix: my FancyButton usercontrol causes a page refresh. For comparison I'm also using a traditional LinkButton, which works as intended.

```
//Doesn't work: Causes whole page to refresh/reload.
<as:FancyButton ID="fbUpload"
    runat="server" Text="FancyButton"/>

//Works as intended: Causes ajax refresh of Update Panel.
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="LinkButton" />
```

Here's my updatePanel code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upNewUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
    runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="fbUpload" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="detailPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here is the code for the FancyButton UserControl:
**I am pretty sure the problem is in here:**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;


namespace Jake
{
    public class FancyButton : WebControl, INamingContainer
    {
        private LinkButton _btn;


        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return _btn.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                _btn.Text = value;
            }
        }

        public string OnClientClick
        {
            get 
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return _btn.OnClientClick;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                _btn.OnClientClick = value;
            }
        }

        public delegate void ClickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
        public event ClickEventHandler Click = delegate { };

        protected void _btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Click(this, e);
        }



        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            EnsureChildControls();
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();

            _btn = new LinkButton { ID = "btn" };
            Controls.Add(_btn);

        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {   
            //<a class="btn {Color} btn-{Color}{CssClass?}{hasImage?}">
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "fancyButton");
            _btn.RenderBeginTag(writer);

            if (Text != null)
            {
                writer.Write(Text);
            }

            _btn.RenderEndTag(writer);

        }
    }
}
```

**TL;DR: The normal linkbutton works as an async trigger; my custom, UserControl button does not. What am I doing wrong?**

---

**Solution from accepted answer**

By inheriting `LinkButton` instead of `WebControl`, the Async panel update works as intended. Also, all of those pesky `override` methods became unnecessary.

```
namespace Jake
{
    public class FancyButton : LinkButton
    {
        public string Color
        {
            get
            {
                if ( ViewState["Color"] != null && ((string)ViewState["Color"]).Length > 0)
                {
                    return ((string)ViewState["Color"]).ToLower();
                }
                else return "white";
            }
            set { ViewState["Color"] = value; }
        }
        public string Icon
        {
            get { return (string)ViewState["Icon"]; }
            set { ViewState["Icon"] = value; }
        }
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            //<a class="btn {Color} btn-{Color}{CssClass?}{hasImage?}">
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, string.Format("fancyButton {0}{1}{2}",
                this.Color,
                CssClass.Length > 0 ? " " + CssClass : string.Empty,
                Icon != null && Icon.Length > 0 ? " hasIcon" : String.Empty));
            this.RenderBeginTag(writer);

            // <span>
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);

            // <div class="icon {IconClass}"></div>
            if (Icon != null)
            {
                writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, string.Format("icon {0}{1}",
                    Icon,
                    Text != null ? " btnIconPadding" : ""));
                writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
                writer.RenderEndTag();
            }
            if (Text != null)
            {
                writer.Write(Text);
            }

            // </span>
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            this.RenderEndTag(writer);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET updatepanel always invokes a normal postback and full page life cycle, the only difference is that the browser will not flicker because it will redraw only the content of the UpdatePanel in a smart way, not the whole page.

Comment: If you mean the page is executing its lifecycle, then David is correct.  If you mean the page is flickering, then I'm not sure.  I haven't used an UpdatePanel in years—for good reason

Comment: When I say "Page Refresh" I mean the "flicker", as in not asynchronous. Updated for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure on this, but I'm guessing that the problem is that the button causing postback is a private one from inside your UserControl, which you can't add to your triggers so easily.

The cleanest workaround I can think of is to make a class that inherits from LinkButton for your customizable control rather than a UserControl. Disadvantage: no visual designer or markup page.

A quick Google on the issue brought me indirectly to a Microsoft Connect:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/524827/dynamicdataentities-site-linkbutton-in-updatepanel#details

(Don't bother reading the thread he links from ASP.NET forums unless you like banging your head on the wall)

Comment: Works perfectly now. Also, by inheriting LinkButton instead of WebControl, I was also able to remove all methods in that class except for `Render()`. Thanks!